# Cached images in UIWebView take longer to load? (NSURLProtocol?)

Tags: ios, ios6, uiwebview, mobile-safari

I'm serving up local images to my UIWebView via NSURLProtocol (which means the image is returned almost immediately), but I'm experiencing an issue where cached images (images being displayed again after their first load) take longer to load. Is there something in my NSURLProtocol causing this?

```
@implementation URLProtocol

+ (BOOL) canInitWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request {
    return  [request.URL.scheme isEqualToString:@"file"] ||
            [request.URL.scheme isEqualToString:@"http"];
}

+ (NSURLRequest*) canonicalRequestForRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request {
    return request;
}

- (void) startLoading {
    id<NSURLProtocolClient> client = self.client;
    NSURLRequest* request = self.request;
    NSString *fileToLoad = request.URL.absoluteString;
    NSURLResponse *response;

    if([fileToLoad hasPrefix:@"http://app-fullpath/"]){
        fileToLoad = [fileToLoad stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"http://app-fullpath/" withString:@""];
    } else {
        fileToLoad = [[NSURL URLWithString:fileToLoad] path];
    }

    NSData* data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:fileToLoad];

    response = [[NSHTTPURLResponse alloc] initWithURL:[request URL] statusCode:200 HTTPVersion:@"HTTP/1.1" headerFields:[NSDictionary dictionary]];

    [client URLProtocol:self didReceiveResponse:response cacheStoragePolicy:NSURLCacheStorageNotAllowed];
    [client URLProtocol:self didLoadData:data];
    [client URLProtocolDidFinishLoading:self];
}

- (void) stopLoading { }
@end
```

Any speed suggestions, javascript/html or iOS?

Comment: Why would you load local images into UIWebView ?

Comment: There are many uses, such as HTML application, and the fact that UIWebView can be easier to manipulate than a UITextView. It is the best option in my case.

Comment: Another use case is for loading up localized images. You can make a request for a local png, check the current locale at runtime and load a different image. You could also use it for dynamic theming by loading an alternate css without change the path in the HTML.

Comment: @SandyChapman Absolutely. Where were you when I first asked this question! :)

Comment: Just stumbled on your question while looking to implement my own NSURLProtocol subclass. I usually try to add to the conversation if I have anything relevant to add as it might help others when they come across the question. Upvotes for your Q&A.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My problem was that UIWebView gives text a much higher priority than images, so text is laid out first, then images are processed. In order to fix that I created a DOM representation of my HTML & Images, then I replaced all images with images loaded via javascript (`new Image()`) and they show instantly.

Comment: Could you please tell me how you did that ?

Comment: @Vijay I don't recommend this solution anymore, as it's inefficient, and doesn't address all cases. If you are having this problem, try eliminating the cache.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I want to load images from html. please have a look at the question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35863295/ios-9-0-uiwebview-behaviour-on-wifi

Comment: When I load the html page first time then everything work well but if I load same url multiple times then webview waits 20-25 seconds after some data downloads and again continue downloading the remaining data.