# iOS 9.0 UIWebView Behaviour on WiFi

Tags: ios, uiwebview

**Use-case:**

We are using UIWebview to load HTML, contents are different text,images and raw data. 
We are using NSURLProtocol to observe redirected URLs for UIWebview. We are observing by NSURLConnection, How much data load for each redirected URL.

**Delegate Observation:**

- On WiFi for continuous two iteration on UIWebview "loadRequest", 1st
  iteration works fine, but 2nd iteration few URL take time to load,
  that URLs are most of image URLs.
- On Cellular for continuous ten    iteration, it will work as
  expected with same HTML.

**Q: Why this is on WiFi, only?**

- We don't have any implementation Network wise.
- Same implementation works fine on Cellular.

Please let me know, If this any webkit issue for WiFi or any WiFi policy for iOS 9.0.

Comment: What does your NSURLProtocol look like?

Comment: [Link](https://www.raywenderlich.com/59982/nsurlprotocol-tutorial)